# get picture from database(close)

Tags: vb.net

this is my success code:

```
     Private Sub dg1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dg1.CellContentClick
    Label5.Text = dg1.Item(0, e.RowIndex).Value
    Label6.Text = dg1.Item(2, e.RowIndex).Value
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\USERS\USER\DOWNLOADS\SDP(BACKUP1)\SDP(BACKUP)\SDP.MDF;Integrated Security=True"
    con.Open()
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "select picture from Announcement where name = @name"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", dg1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value())
    da.SelectCommand = cmd

    Dim imageData As Byte() = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
    If Not imageData Is Nothing Then
        Using ms As New MemoryStream(imageData, 0, imageData.Length)
            ms.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length)
            PictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(ms, True)
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

i had success get my picture from database. which add paramater to name, then parameter name with @name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not loading a picture from a `DataGridView` at all.  You're trying to query a database and it's failing.  Nothing to do with grids or images.  Plain and simple, you've written bad SQL code.  If you're going to include a text literal then it needs to have single quotes around it.  Better still, do it properly and use parameters.

The issue is, as I have said, in your SQL code:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select picture from Announcement where name =" & dg1.Item(0, e.RowIndex).Value & ""
```

You are inserting a value for the `name` column into that SQL code so it becomes text literal.  As I said, text literals require single quotes.  Where are your single quotes?  You don't have any.  That's the issue.  If you were going to use string concatenation like that, which you should not, then it would need to look like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select picture from Announcement where name = '" & dg1.Item(0, e.RowIndex).Value & "'"
```

If you were to do it properly, which involves using parameters, as I said, then it would look something like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select picture from Announcement where name = @name"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", CStr(dg1.Item(0, e.RowIndex).Value))
```

or like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select picture from Announcement where name = @name"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = CStr(dg1.Item(0, e.RowIndex).Value)
```

Comment: my logic is...get picture from database to picture box base on the name in datagridview.

Comment: A `String` is a `String`, whether it comes from a `DataGridViewCell`, a `TextBox`, a file or wherever.  The grid is irrelevant to the issue.  The issue is as I have already told you, which you have apparently ignored.

Comment: i know what you mean.
but i dunt know what to do now...may give me some guide?

izzit parameter the picturebox2 then use IO.File.ReadAllBytes?

Comment: now this error come out

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: The data types text and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.**

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `text` data type for a start.  It's been deprecated for quite some time.  If you can, change that to `varchar` or, if required, `nvarchar`.  If you can't do that, or even if you can, you can call `Add` rather than `AddWithValue` and specify the data type of the parameter, then set it's `Value` property afterwards.

Comment: ar....another problem come out...

**A generic error occurred in GDI+.** is what error???

Comment: That is a completely separate issue and should be addressed in a completely new question that provides all the relevant information for that issue and nothing irrelevant.

Comment: Don't forget to accept this answer if it has indeed answered your question.